# Chrome not dispatching click/dblclick events when alt-key is pressed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onclick, mouseevent

Messing around with keys when trying to add some functionality led me to discover that chrome does not seem to dispatch mouse-click events when the alt-key is held.

My problem is that this is not universal. There seems to be no rhyme or reason when an event will be dispatched!

I have tested this in Firefox and it consistently dispatches events, even with alt-key held down.

This problem is specific to the `click` and `dblclick` events. `mousedown` and `mouseup` dispatches events consistently.

Has anyone else encountered this behavior? Is it a bug? What is going on here?

Edit: Fiddle that demonstrates behaviour:
https://jsfiddle.net/a28rLjb6/

Comment: Those events fire just fine for me when holding down alt key, http://jsfiddle.net/yz3xonmd/ . Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are getting

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/a28rLjb6/

Comment: Do you get same behavior with extensions disabled? Have you tried preventing default?

Comment: That is because of the default behavior of chrome to download the url of a `<a href>` element when alt-clicking. not sure you can prevent that behavior

Comment: @charlietfl Where do I `preventDefault`? That call usually goes in the event handler. No event arrives to be handled. That's the problem. Also, tested in incognito, no extensions are at fault here.

Comment: I get this issue on FF and Chromium on Linux Mint, Alt + Click seems to drag a window, which I found can be changed in the `Windows > Behavior Tab > Special Keys to Move and Resize Windows`, https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=264172